# Verify what website I am currently on

Tags: vbscript

Does anyone know of a quick and easy way to verify what website I'm currently on?

I have made some script that logs me into a website, but if the user is already logged on, it will create an error.

If anyone knows a good way to tell if they are already logged in, please let me know!

### The script is as follows:

```
Username = InputBox("Please input username")
Password = InputBox("Please input password")

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim IE
Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
IE.Visible = 1
IE.navigate "http://wsmmart.itg.ti.com/"

Do
    WScript.Sleep 250
Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy

IE.Document.All.Item("fld2").Value = Username
IE.Document.All.Item("fld5").Value = Password
'IE.Document.All.Item("Submit").Click
```

Comment: Does the site not have something you can parse which shows "logged in" or something? Most websites which have log-ins have some sort of text on the site you should be able to parse. Perhaps look into what your site shows for a logged in user and parse, check for this, and then determine whether the user is logged in.

Comment: Simply navigate through logout URL before login into website.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will loop through all open IE windows and look to see if any one of them has the term "wsmmart.itg.ti." in the url.  If it finds a match it will control that window and proceed to insert your username, pw, etc.  If it doesn't find a match then you could run your code to open a new window

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location

    If my_url Like "*" & "wsmmart.itg.ti." & "*" Then 'find an existing wsmmart web page
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        Exit For
    Else
        if x=(IE_count - 1) then
           ' do your stuff to open a new window
        end if
    End If
Next

on error goto 0
```

now try to insert your username, pw, etc. , put it in an if statement.  if you get an error back, then you're already logged in